# OpenMP compiling executing

Tags: c++, linux, openmp

I'm using linux and I don't know which is the command line to compile an OpenMP file, can I simply write:

```
g++ myprog.cpp -o myprog
```

or `g++` compiler doesn't work?

And how I execute `myprog`? Where I choose the number of threads?

Comment: use `g++ -fopenmp myprog.cpp -o myprog`. And you can set the number of threads by using the environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS.

Comment: Don't forget the `-Wall` argument to `g++` to get all warnings; you may want debug info with `-g`, and optimization with `-O1` (in addition of `-fopenmp` ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to compile with `-fopenmp` and before you run the executable, set the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` variable to set the number of threads, for example with `export` in bash. An example from [here](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/intro_openmp/compile_run.html):

```
$ gcc -o omp_helloc -fopenmp omp_hello.c
$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
$ ./omp_helloc
Hello World from thread = 0
Hello World from thread = 1
Number of threads = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the negative votes! No more question from my account! (my thanks are also coming from all those people who are studying and need answers)